# Django send_mass_mail over 300 mail errors

Tags: django

I have a Django project with Gunicorn and Nginx. I have to send over 300 mail. First, I solved Connection Timed Out 504Nginx with proxy_.._timeouts. After that, I got Bad Getaway 502. I try some solutions, but I couldn't send mails because Bad Getaway 502 arisen.  How to configure nginx to send over 300 mails at once?

Comment: you could try to increase your nginx timeout, I believe it's 60 seconds by default

Comment: @sebb keepalive_timeout or another ones ?

Comment: proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600; everything in seconds